# This code should display the image specified in the link in the image view

Tags: android, firebase, picasso

```
Picasso.with(this).load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/student-help-portal.appspot.com/o/3bcea.PNG?alt=media&token=90466ef2-6072-4861-849f-f1625135125d").into(imageview); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_photo);
```

Comment: This code should display it but it isn't. What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your code like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_photo); 
Picasso.with(this).load("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/student-help-portal.appspot.com/o/3bcea.PNG?alt=media&token=90466ef2-6072-4861-849f-f1625135125d").into(imageview);
```

Answer (score 2):

Set content view and only after that load the image